# How to get rolling correlation on Python Polars?

Tags: correlation, rolling-computation, python-polars

How to get rolling correlation in Python Polars?
Or at least correlation per row like:
`pl.cor(pl.col('col_1'), pl.col('col_2'))`

I am aware of Pandas solution:

```
pd_df = result_df.to_pandas()
rol_corr_df = pd_df['col_1'].rolling(5).corr(pd_df['col_2'])
pl_df = pl_df.with_columns(correlation=pl.from_pandas(rol_corr_df))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polars has `groupby_rolling` but it needs to be pointed to a time or integer column by which it'll group.

If you just want it to groupby rows then you can use `with_row_count` to create an index. However, `with_row_count` makes a uint32 and `groupby_rolling` wants a signed int so you have to cast it.

Assume we start with

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':np.random.uniform(1,100,100), 'b':np.random.uniform(1,100,100), })
```

then we could do the following:

```
df \
    .with_row_count('i') \
    .with_columns(i=pl.col('i').cast(pl.Int32())) \
    .groupby_rolling('i', period='10i') \
    .agg(rolling_corr=pl.corr('a','b')) \
    .drop('i')

shape: (100, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ rolling_corr │
│ ---          │
│ f64          │
╞══════════════╡
│ NaN          │
│ 1.0          │
│ -0.419386    │
│ -0.322489    │
│ …            │
│ -0.333332    │
│ -0.027533    │
│ 0.081232     │
│ 0.151985     │
└──────────────┘
```

Note in the `groupby_rolling`, the period is set to a string 10i. If you had a datetime then there are more options, see [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html#polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling)

Comment: Not so graceful as Pandas solution but more performant. Thank you.